# What is wrong with this AES 128 encryption?

Tags: java, security, encryption, cryptography

I can't understand why my cipher is longer than the expected output based on the following vectors. I won't explain the code because I think it is very tidy and clear.

```
package mundo;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

class AESTest {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     //each array is a vector case {key, plainText, expectedCipher}
     String[][] cases = new String[][]{{"00000000000000000000000000000000", "f34481ec3cc627bacd5dc3fb08f273e6","0336763e966d92595a567cc9ce537f5e"},
                                       {"00000000000000000000000000000000", "9798c4640bad75c7c3227db910174e72", "a9a1631bf4996954ebc093957b234589"},
                                       {"2b7e151628aed2a6abf7158809cf4f3c", "6bc1bee22e409f96e93d7e117393172a", "3ad77bb40d7a3660a89ecaf32466ef97"},
                                       {"2b7e151628aed2a6abf7158809cf4f3c", "ae2d8a571e03ac9c9eb76fac45af8e51", "f5d3d58503b9699de785895a96fdbaaf"}};
     for(String[] kase : cases)
     {
         byte[] theKey = byte2hex(kase[0]);
         byte[] theMsg = byte2hex(kase[1]);
         byte[] theExp = byte2hex(kase[2]);
         Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
         SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(theKey, "AES");
         cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec);
         byte[] cryptMsg = cipher.doFinal(theMsg);
         System.out.println("Key     : "+hex2byte(theKey));
         System.out.println("Message : "+hex2byte(theMsg));
         System.out.println("Cipher  : "+hex2byte(cryptMsg));
         System.out.println("Expected: "+hex2byte(theExp) + "\n");
     }
   }
   public static String hex2byte(byte[] array) {
        return DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(array);
   }
   public static byte[] byte2hex(String s) {
        return DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(s);
   }
}
```

This is the output:

```
Key     : 00000000000000000000000000000000
Message : F34481EC3CC627BACD5DC3FB08F273E6
Cipher  : 0336763E966D92595A567CC9CE537F5E0143DB63EE66B0CDFF9F69917680151E
Expected: 0336763E966D92595A567CC9CE537F5E

Key     : 00000000000000000000000000000000
Message : 9798C4640BAD75C7C3227DB910174E72
Cipher  : A9A1631BF4996954EBC093957B2345890143DB63EE66B0CDFF9F69917680151E
Expected: A9A1631BF4996954EBC093957B234589

Key     : 2B7E151628AED2A6ABF7158809CF4F3C
Message : 6BC1BEE22E409F96E93D7E117393172A
Cipher  : 3AD77BB40D7A3660A89ECAF32466EF97A254BE88E037DDD9D79FB6411C3F9DF8
Expected: 3AD77BB40D7A3660A89ECAF32466EF97

Key     : 2B7E151628AED2A6ABF7158809CF4F3C
Message : AE2D8A571E03AC9C9EB76FAC45AF8E51
Cipher  : F5D3D58503B9699DE785895A96FDBAAFA254BE88E037DDD9D79FB6411C3F9DF8
Expected: F5D3D58503B9699DE785895A96FDBAAF
```

Why is the Cipher longer than Expected. This are trusted 128 bit AES vectors taken from reference books.

**EDIT** added to code:

```
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec);
byte[] dcrypMsg = cipher.doFinal(cryptMsg);
System.out.println("Decrypted: " + byte2hex(dcrypMsg) + "\n");
```

Decryption is correct, but I still can't understand...

```
Key     : 2B7E151628AED2A6ABF7158809CF4F3C
Message : AE2D8A571E03AC9C9EB76FAC45AF8E51
Cipher  : F5D3D58503B9699DE785895A96FDBAAFA254BE88E037DDD9D79FB6411C3F9DF8
Expected: F5D3D58503B9699DE785895A96FDBAAF
Decrypted: AE2D8A571E03AC9C9EB76FAC45AF8E51
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please use `Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");`
to make sure, your input does not get padded. 
Then I get the expected output for all of your test cases.

According to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html:

> A transformation is of the form:
>
> "algorithm/mode/padding" or "algorithm" (in the latter case,
>   provider-specific default values for the mode and padding scheme are
>   used).

You do not know, what kind of padding is used if you do not specify it. I assume your input data gets padded, which means something is added to your input to fill it up, such you have a set of full blocks of the blocksize of your cipher. Your input length is already divisible by the blocksize, so a full block gets added, resulting in the Message, having twice the expected length.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not specify the cipherblock chaining mode and the padding algorithm, then the JDK will take defaults. The crypto specification advises against not specifying them:

> It is recommended to use a transformation that fully specifies the
>   algorithm, mode, and padding. By not doing so, the provider will use a
>   default. For example, **the SunJCE and SunPKCS11 providers uses ECB as
>   the default mode, and PKCS5Padding as the default padding for many
>   symmetric ciphers.**
>   *http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#trans*

To get your desired output, you need to use the Electronic Cookbook mode (ECB) - so no block chaining - and no padding:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
```